# Typo3 Calendar Base (Ext:cal) - alter the search result event list view

Tags: typo3

I am trying to alter the list view. I wish to add image and adapt the html.

There is marker like:

```
<!-- ###LIST### start -->
<!-- ###LIST### end -->
```

Which gets has all html in it. How do I add/edit this html?

Classes/Model/EventModel.php seemed promising as it has lot of markers. But no idea how to use them. The TS too has lot of config and hardly any documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can change everything in EXT:cal.

**List view**

Changing a event in the list in event_model.html. There are four blocks. Two for events odd and even and allday events.

```
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT_LIST_ODD### start -->
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT_LIST_ODD### end -->

<!-- ###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT_LIST_EVEN### start -->
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT_LIST_EVEN### end -->

<!-- ###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT_LIST_ODD_ALLDAY### start -->
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT_LIST_ODD_ALLDAY### end -->

<!-- ###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT_LIST_EVEN_ALLDAY### start -->
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT_LIST_EVEN_ALLDAY### end -->
```

You have to change all four blocks to catch all variants.

Some formats must be done in Typoscript. To change a event in a list go to

```
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.event
```

**Detail view**

And to go further to the detail view of a event. In event_model.html you have this two blocks. Use it the same way.

```
<!--###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT### begin -->
<!--###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT### end -->

<!--###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT_ALLDAY### begin -->
<!--###TEMPLATE_PHPICALENDAR_EVENT_ALLDAY### end -->
```

And in Typoscript event detail is in

```
plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.event.event
```